# How can I access an action 2 header in Sails 1?

Tags: sails.js

Action 2 in Sails 1 is some very new, but I'm struggling to develop an application with it. However, when doing some processes, such as token attention, I need to access the token that comes from the request header and because Action 2 receives only inputs and exits, I can not access the request and its headers with them. Anyone who can help me with exits creation materials would be a great help as well. I'm willing to blog my findings for future developers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With actions2,  you can access the request object with `this.req`.

Comment: what action 2 or 1 means?

Comment: @imFSN see https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#actions2

Answer (score 0):

You can access the header by this.req.headers inside the action method.

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    sails.log.debug(inputs);
    sails.log.debug(this.req.headers);
    ...
}
```

The output will be something like:

> debug: { 'content-type': 'application/json',   token:
>   '3f892682b21d4a649cc93e541b1b05405512eee6',   'cache-control':
>   'no-cache',   'postman-token': 'eafa2bc7-5576-4acb-8f8d-91ebc9365e32',
>   'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.6.0',   accept: '*/*',   host:
>   'localhost:1337',   cookie:
>   'sails.sid=s%3AUIHK5FhQjC-prYvonucFBR4hnrxgNO8R.kvoR4EMgzR2%2F%2Btg8pIFKNcsmYgPQsn6xOQp5aSmJuX4',
>   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',   'content-length': '62',
>   connection: 'keep-alive' }

Please check the official documentation on: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-headers